# Using an annotation to Serialize Null in Moshi with nested Event

Tags: android, serialization, adapter, moshi

I am attempting to add a custom annotation to serialize specific values in my model to null when calling the `toJSON` method from Moshi. I have something working based on this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254876/moshi-custom-qualifier-annotation-to-serialise-null-on-one-property-only) but it's falling short for me when I have a nested object.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class EventWrapper(
    @SerializeNulls val event: Event?,
    @SerializeNulls val queries: Queries? = null) {

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Queries(val stub: String?)

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Event(
       val action: String?,
       val itemAction: String)
}
```

If I pass null to `event` or `queries` they are serialized as:

```
{
    'event': null,
    'query': null
}
```

The issue is when event isn't null there are fields inside of it I would like to not serialize if they are null such as action. My preferred result would be this:

```
{
    'event': {
        'itemAction': "test" 
    },
    'query': null
}
```

But instead I am getting:

```
{
    'event': {
        'action': null,
        'itemAction': "test" 
    },
    'query': null
}
```

Here is the code for my custom adapter based on the linked response:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @JsonQualifier
 annotation class SerializeNulls {
     companion object {
         var JSON_ADAPTER_FACTORY: JsonAdapter.Factory = object : JsonAdapter.Factory {

             @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
             override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation?>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
                 val nextAnnotations = Types.nextAnnotations(annotations, SerializeNulls::class.java)

                 return if (nextAnnotations == null) {
                     null
                 } else {
                     moshi.nextAdapter<Any>(this, type, nextAnnotations).serializeNulls()
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Su-Au Hwang's answer in thread worked for me. Which is better than creating custom adapters for our models. Thanks.

Here is same code with Kotlin:

1. Create a new adapter `NullIfNullJsonAdapter`

   ```kotlin
   class NullIfNullJsonAdapter<T>(val delegate: JsonAdapter<T>) : JsonAdapter<T>() {

           override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): T? {
               return delegate.fromJson(reader)
           }

           override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: T?) {
               if (value == null) {
                   val serializeNulls: Boolean = writer.serializeNulls
                   writer.serializeNulls = true
                   try {
                       delegate.toJson(writer, value)
                   } finally {
                       writer.serializeNulls = serializeNulls
                   }
               } else {
                   delegate.toJson(writer, value)
               }
           }

           override fun toString(): String {
               return "$delegate.serializeNulls()"
           }
       }
   ```
2. Create `JsonQualifier` that you can use for annotation

   ```kotlin
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    @JsonQualifier
    annotation class SerializeNull {
        companion object {
            object Factory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
                override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
                    val nextAnnotations = Types.nextAnnotations(annotations, SerializeNull::class.java)

                    return if (nextAnnotations == null) {
                        null
                    } else {
                        NullIfNullJsonAdapter<Any>(moshi.nextAdapter(this, type, nextAnnotations))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Add Factory to moshi builder

   ```kotlin
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
                .add(SerializeNull.Companion.Factory)
                .build()
   ```
4. Annotate property with `@SerializeNull` (e.g. host)

   ```kotlin
    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Event(
         val name: String,
         @SerializeNull val host: Host?,
         val venue: String?,
     )
   ```

---

**Some tests**

```kotlin
 @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
 data class Host(val firstName: String, val lastName: String?)

 @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
 data class Event(
     val name: String,
     @SerializeNull val host: Host?,
     val venue: String?,
 )


 @Test
 fun `everything is added to json if object has everything`() {
     val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
         .add(SerializeNull.Companion.Factory)
         .build()
     val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Event> = moshi.adapter()
     val event = Event(
         name = "Birthday Party",
         host = Host(firstName = "Harsh", lastName = "Bhakta"),
         venue = "House"
     )
     val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(event)
     assertEquals("""{"name":"Birthday Party","host":{"firstName":"Harsh","lastName":"Bhakta"},"venue":"House"}""", json)
 }

 @Test
 fun `check host  is null in json since host is annotated with serializeNull and venue is excluded because it's not annotated`() {
     val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
         .add(SerializeNull.Companion.Factory)
         .build()
     val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Event> = moshi.adapter()
     val event = Event(
         name = "Birthday Party",
         host = null,
         venue = null
     )
     val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(event)
     assertEquals("""{"name":"Birthday Party","host":null}""", json)
 }

 @Test
 fun `check nested property (host lastname) is not included if it's null because it's not annotated with SerializeNull`() {
     val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
         .add(SerializeNull.Companion.Factory)
         .build()
     val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Event> = moshi.adapter()
     val event = Event(
         name = "Birthday Party",
         host = Host(firstName = "Harsh", lastName = null),
         venue = null
     )
     val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(event)
     assertEquals("""{"name":"Birthday Party","host":{"firstName":"Harsh"}}""", json)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue and the only solution I found was to make a custom adapter instead of using the SerializeNulls annotation. This way, it will only serialize nulls if the object is null, and serialize it normally with the generated adapter otherwise.

```
class EventJsonAdapter {
    private val adapter = Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(Event::class.java)

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, event: Event?) {
        if (event == null) {
            with(writer) {
                serializeNulls = true
                nullValue()
                serializeNulls = false
            }
        } else {
            adapter.toJson(writer, event)
        }
    }
}
```

For the generated adapter to work don't forget to annotate the Event class with:

> @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)

The custom adapter can then be added to the moshi builder like this:

> Moshi.Builder().add(EventJsonAdapter()).build()

In my case I only needed this for one model in specific. Probably not a good solution if you need it for several, in which case the annotation is more practical, but I'll leave it here since it might help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `.serializeNulls()` returns an adapter that serializes `nulls` all the way down the tree.

You can simply copy the implementation for `.serializeNulls()` and add null check in the `toJson` method and only use it if it's `null` like this (sorry for my Java):

```
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter;
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonReader;
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class NullIfNullJsonAdapter<T> extends JsonAdapter<T> {
    final JsonAdapter<T> delegate;

    public NullIfNullJsonAdapter(JsonAdapter<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable
    T fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        return delegate.fromJson(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public void toJson(JsonWriter writer, @Nullable T value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            boolean serializeNulls = writer.getSerializeNulls();
            writer.setSerializeNulls(true);
            try {
                delegate.toJson(writer, value);
            } finally {
                writer.setSerializeNulls(serializeNulls);
            }
        } else {
            delegate.toJson(writer, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return delegate + ".serializeNulls()";
    }
}
```

and then you can use it in the `@JsonQualifier`

```
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter;
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier;
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi;
import com.squareup.moshi.Types;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
public @interface SerializeNulls {
    JsonAdapter.Factory JSON_ADAPTER_FACTORY = new JsonAdapter.Factory() {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public JsonAdapter<?> create(Type type, Set<? extends Annotation> annotations, Moshi moshi) {
            Set<? extends Annotation> nextAnnotations =
                    Types.nextAnnotations(annotations, SerializeNulls.class);
            if (nextAnnotations == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return new NullIfNullJsonAdapter(moshi.nextAdapter(this, type, nextAnnotations));
        }
    };
}
```