# Retrofit/Moshi : Deserialize and keep null fields

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I've seen many topics about this subject but none of them fit my needs.

I need a way to deserialize null fields into null json properties

Let's take this example:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class MyClass(val myField: String?)

val obj = MyClass(null)
```

expected behavior:

```
{
   "myField: null
}
```

By default, it just skips null fields.

I'm working with Retrofit and Moshi.
I don't want to enable `withNullSerialization` as it will take effect to all Classes (and break the existing logic) and I want this to work for only one Class for now.

Furthermore, for performance and apk size purpose, I removed `kotlin-reflect` from the project. Which means I would like to avoid using reflection (`KotlinJsonAdapterFactory`) as many solutions point to that direction.

Is there a way to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use an annotation to do it for just one class. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254876/moshi-custom-qualifier-annotation-to-serialise-null-on-one-property-only/52265735#52265735

Comment: This approach requires reflection with the KotlinJsonAdapterFactory which I would like to avoid

Comment: It does not. The example uses that factory, but the SerializeNulls annotation in the answer does not require it.

Comment: It worked. Indeed kotlin-reflect is not required. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doc, seems you need to write a [custom adapter](https://github.com/square/moshi#composing-adapters) for that specific class:

```
class MyClassWithNullsAdapter {
  @ToJson fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, myClass: MyClass?,
    delegate: JsonAdapter<MyClass?>) {
    val wasSerializeNulls: Boolean = writer.getSerializeNulls()
    writer.setSerializeNulls(true)
    try {
      delegate.toJson(writer, myClass)
    } finally {
      writer.setLenient(wasSerializeNulls)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I'll check it out and get back to you

Comment: I used Eric Cochran's approach for a more convenient way. Thanks anyway